# SwiftUI - Making a String to conform to a View

Tags: string, swiftui, view

I want to load a new view. If I phrase the code as:

```
NavigationLink("Target", destination: TargetView() )
```

it works. But if I have a string var of food.target = "TargetView()"

```
NavigationLink("Target", destination: (food.target))
```

It doesn't work as the string doesn't conform to a view. Can you metamorphose a string into a destination view for these purposes?

Comment: Oh... hmm... what are you trying to do here? Why are you storing `"TargetView()"` as text? Are you expecting the literal text "TargetView()" to appear on the screen? Or are you wanting that to show the `TargetView`?

Comment: Do different foods have different views that you want to navigate to?

Comment: Yes - I have a list of "foods" and want to go a new view in each instance. So the TargetView is, ideally, stored in an array.

Comment: Are you sure you just don't want the same view for each food just with different content inside the view? i.e. the view will look the same but it will say "Spaghetti" or "Apple" and have a picture or nutritional info based on the food being displayed?

Comment: Food is actually celestial variables and each item needs a very different display. I only used "food" to simplify the question. My stupid.

Comment: I'm not sure what a celestial variable is. But you can't just store code in a string and expect that to run. You need a way to create a `View` from your data. It would be easier if we could see a better idea of what your data actually looks like.

Comment: a `View` should never be held in a model. Look up the new `navigationDestination` along with `NavigationStack`

Comment: I have coded this alternatively with some if statements with the View name spelt out, and it works. Whilst I understand why the SwiftUI compiler doesn't like to do this from a programming point of view it be nice is if there was a call so that in a struct/array which could have the name of a view in it and be able to call it and have it popped.